# php state array no display

Tags: php, arrays

Below is the code I am attempting to use to dispaly a drop down menu that allows the user to select the state that they live in.  Only problem is that the dropdown displays only blank values. The list is long as if the states are there but every slot is blank?  Any help for this would be awesome!

```
            <div>
        <?php $state_array = array(
'AL'=>'Alabama',
'AK'=>'Alaska',
'AZ'=>'Arizona',
'AR'=>'Arkansas',
'CA'=>'California',
'CO'=>'Colorado',
'CT'=>'Connecticut',
'DE'=>'Delaware',
'DC'=>'District of Columbia',
'FL'=>'Florida',
'GA'=>'Georgia',
'HI'=>'Hawaii',
'ID'=>'Idaho',
'IL'=>'Illinois',
'IN'=>'Indiana',
'IA'=>'Iowa',
'KS'=>'Kansas',
'KY'=>'Kentucky',
'LA'=>'Louisiana',
'ME'=>'Maine',
'MD'=>'Maryland',
'MA'=>'Massachusetts',
'MI'=>'Michigan',
'MN'=>'Minnesota',
'MS'=>'Mississippi',
'MO'=>'Missouri',
'MT'=>'Montana',
'NE'=>'Nebraska',
'NV'=>'Nevada',
'NH'=>'New Hampshire',
'NJ'=>'New Jersey',
'NM'=>'New Mexico',
'NY'=>'New York',
'NC'=>'North Carolina',
'ND'=>'North Dakota',
'OH'=>'Ohio',
'OK'=>'Oklahoma',
'OR'=>'Oregon',
'PA'=>'Pennsylvania',
'RI'=>'Rhode Island',
'SC'=>'South Carolina',
'SD'=>'South Dakota',
'TN'=>'Tennessee',
'TX'=>'Texas',
'UT'=>'Utah',
'VT'=>'Vermont',
'VA'=>'Virginia',
'WA'=>'Washington',
'WV'=>'West Virginia',
'WI'=>'Wisconsin',
'WY'=>'Wyoming',
); ?>
            State: 
            <select id="state" name="state"> 
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($state_array); $i++) {
                if (isset($state)&&$state == $state_array[$i]) {
                    echo "<option value=\"$state_array[$i]\" selected=\"selected\">$state_array[$i]</option>";
                } else {
                    echo "<option value=\"$state_array[$i]\">$state_array[$i]</option>";
                }
            } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using numeric indexes to iterate through associative array. You shoud use the `foreach` loop for this instead of the `for` loop:

```
<?php foreach ($state_array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
} ?>
```

Additionally: if I may suggest that you use `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, that would make your life much easier, and would have helped you to avoid this mistake :)

Comment: Thank you, stupid mistake on my part! This is a timely and great response. I will accept answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Your keys in the array are the two letter combos "WI/WY" etc. You try to loop and access with numerical index.

You can change your loop to:

```
foreach ($state_array as $short => $state) {
   // $short is WI/WY
   // $state is Wisconsin/Wyoming
}
```